# Instagram ios hooking in ios 6.0

Tags: ios, instagram, ios6

In one of my app instagram exclusive ios hooking is not working in ios 6.0. Same code is working fine in ios 5.0. Any idea why it's not working?

I am using the following things described in this link
http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/ under Document Interaction section.

**"Alternatively, if you want to show only Instagram in the application list (instead of Instagram plus any other public/jpeg-conforming apps) you can specify the extension class igo, which is of type com.instagram.exclusivegram."**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you at least show us the relevant code, or explain what libraries you are using for this? Also, iOS 6.0 is in beta, so you should expect that some things will be broken under it.

Comment: Even with your updates, you haven't stated what "not working" means here. What is not working? You need to provide as much detail as possible for us to have a chance at helping you.

Comment: @BradLarson I am using UIDocumentInteractionController for exclusive hooking of instagram.It is working fine in iOS 5.0 but same code is not working in iOS 6.0. Any help?"not working" mean it's not opening image in instagram app from my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using iOS 6's `UIActivityViewController`, you can use this [UIActivity subclass](http://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram) to share to Instagram. Otherwise, take a look at the code in the `DMActivityInstagram` class' `-(void)performActivity` method for a  working example of Instagram sharing on iOS 6.